# can't change cursor size

Tags: cursor

My cursor seems too small to me (due to 4k screen), i want to make it bigger, i've tried using 
dconf-editor(org.gnome.desktop.interface-cursor size) and 
unity-tweak-tool(larger option)
none of them worked.
By the way i know that i must restart (or log out) my computer to activate the new size.

My ubuntu is 14.04, i've also tried downloading 3 custom cursor theme (krakin, pure-glass and ecliz)
all of them are small and i can't make them bigger, 
I'm kind of new to ubuntu
Any help appreciated ^^

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 16.04 you need to install `dconf-editor` and change `cursor-scale-factor`

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
$ dconf-editor
```

Then, set `com > canonical > unity > interface > cursor-scale-factor` to any number larger than 1. The maximum possible value is 3.